# end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block

Tags: raspberry-pi

How can I solve this problem in `Raspbian Jessie with PIXEL` operating system

> end Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block

Answer (score 0):

You see this error it means that you are having a Raspbian booting problem on the SD card where it is installed.

**Don't panic!** You can still recover the data. I had the same problem and I just connected the SD card to a computer. You can copy your data from there. I copied my data from the SD card to my computer and saved it back onto newly installed version of Raspbian.